# show tagline dynamicaly on bigcommerce Stencil home page

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to know how to show tagline dynamicaly  on home page of bigcommerce, something like this :
http://prntscr.com/e5ieoo
i know it can be possible with banners , but i have already useing the banners on home page for static images . so what is the best way to write tagline on home page  ?

I have find the code on stencil theme home.html

```
{#each shipping_messages}}  
      {{> components/common/alert-info message}} 
   {{/each}}
```

how to use this one for home page ?

Comment: Can you make your image available inline, so to avoid users having to click on unknown links? I'm not a Stencil expert, but maybe insert your tagline into the `components/common` directory, and then just replace the `{#each` with a `{#if true` instead to satisfy the condition for it to display?

Comment: Thanks for reply @sudosoul but i want to add it from admin end !

Comment: The only way admin side would though be to use the banners, unless you modify the theme files directly.